# Leaflet Routing Machine: how to export route coordinates with time associate

Tags: leaflet

I'm using Leaflet Routing Machine with Graphhopper as router. I just want to get routes coordinates and time associate to them. I don't know if it's possible. I only have *summary.totalTime* and *instructions.times*.

But what i want is time according to latLng

```
        // Route informations   
        track.on('routeselected', function(e) {
            var route = e.route;
            var rCoordinates = [],
                i,
                latLng;

            for (i = 0; i < route.coordinates.length; i++) {
                    latLng = L.latLng(route.coordinates[i]);
                    rCoordinates.push([latLng.lng, latLng.lat]);
            }

        console.log(route.summary.totalTime);
        console.log(route.coordinates.length);
        console.log(route);
```